# Can a processor which support DDR3-1600 type of memory also support lower frequency memories?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I want to buy a RAM for "AMD Athlon 5350" processor with specs as mentioned on the link http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/processors/desktop/athlon#. In specification it is written as it will supported memory as DDR3-1600, can I use DDR3-1333 frequency ram with AM1M-S2H gigabyte motherboard with specs as mention on the link http://www.gigabyte.in/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4937#sp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Since both are DDR3, you are good to go. The CPU spec say it supports RAM speeds of 1600. Meaning you can also go below. Sometimes (depending on the ram) you can even go higher. Another good thing to check is the voltge that RAM stick needs to opperate correctly and which is supplied by the motherboard. Make sure your chosen RAM (with taht motherboard) can run with 1.5 V.

Comment: I buy this hardware and using since 1 month and I am frequently getting blue screen error. I check for hard disk and ram errors and it is not showing any error. I also tried changing OS like windows 7, windows 8 and also CentOS even Linux crashed many times and prompted to logout. I search about this problem some websites say that it may be due to hardware configuration miss match.

Comment: Why many processor specification gives memory types supported in or (like DDR3L 1333/1600) for example link http://ark.intel.com/products/84698/Intel-Core-i3-5015U-Processor-3M-Cache-2_10-GHz?_ga=1.131325896.699161083.1432877709 rather than giving only higher memory frequency.

Comment: If you are getting bluescreens you should have asked about this problem, not wether the ram is supported. Ask a new question, providing detailed information, error messages and or when these errors occure. If you believe your ram is faulty, take a look at the tool MemTest.

Comment: I checked ram with MemTest and it is not showing any error.

Comment: then your ram should be fine and the bluescreen should have other causes. But as I sait, you provided no information about that and it's hard to help. Ask a new question.